# Com wrapper and code pages

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, windows-1252

I have a legacy Delphi COM library that accepts an ANSI string (code page 1252) as parameter.
The generated .net wrapper accepts a string for this parameter. Passing in a regular string however doesn't end well. If passed in the '°' character a question mark takes up it's spot.

How can I go and debug this? Is it the com wrapper not recognising the correct encoding? How can I pass in an ANSI string (I can convert it to bytes, but the API requires a string, so it is converted to UTF16 again)

Comment: On your computer, what is the setting for "Language for Non Unicode Programs"?

Comment: Can you name the Delphi COM library? Is it publicly available?

Comment: What happens when you output the string from c# (Via MessageBox for example)? Where do you see the text in your delphi library? In the console, in some file or UI?

Comment: I'm sorry Nineberry. This question is from 2009 :D I no longer work at my first company but I vaguely remember it was a matter of the right configuration when creating the component in Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to write an intermediate layer in an unmanaged language that would redirect calls to the original library and use MultiByteToWideChar for conversion. That's quite easy and a good solution if you don't convince the wrapper some other way.